# Run shell script on windows machine, but the the while do loop does terminate?

Tags: bash, shell

I am new to bash script. I want the user to input his choice, but the while-do loop does not terminate. I tired all choices of read [option] but some of them does not work. read -a stop the loop but does not accept the input. I am using windows machine and I am not sure if I need to install some other lib or packages.

I tried: `read -p, read -a, read -r , read`

```
function user_input {
while true; do
    echo "1. choice 1"
    echo "2. choice 2"
  read -p "What choice would you like: [1,2] " ANS
  case $ANS in 
    '1') 
       environment="-A"
       break;;
    '2') 
       environment="-B" 
       break;;   
    *) 
       echo "Wrong input, try again";;
  esac
done
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you have a `case` nested in a `while`, you should use `break 2` to break both. Otherwise define a variable `CON=true` and set it to false in the `case`.